# Write a query for DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

[Current DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWVIk.png)

Need to Count how many data logged on each day of the week

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpf4U.png)

Whats wrong with this:

```
var res = from c in dtHour.AsEnumerable()
group c by c.Field<string>("Day Logged") into day
let count = day.Count()
select new {
day_s = day.Count()
};
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

The code is not giving the desired output.

Comment: What *is* wrong with it? Do you get an error? The wrong data? A wisp of smoke from your computer? What? More:  [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var collection = dtHour.AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(item => item.Field<string>("Day Logged"))
      .Select(item => new { DayOfWeek = item.Key, Count = item.Count());
```

To print it the way you wanted:

```
Console.WriteLine("Day of week - Count");
foreach(var item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.DayOfWeek + " - " + item.Count);
}
```

Comment: The columns of the data table were created manually,I suppose item.DayLogged will not work.    
I have modified it in this way

Comment: var res = dtHour.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(item => item.Field<String>("Day Logged"))
                .Select(item => new { DayOfWeek = item.Key, Count = item.Count() });

Comment: Im using this query

    var res = dtHour.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(item => item.Field<String>("Day Logged"))
                .Select(item => new { DayOfWeek = item.Key, Count = item.Count() });

Comment: But how do I print the values of variable res

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you changed, and more importantly, *why*.

Comment: @GiladGreen: It works. Thank you So much for your Help.

Comment: @Gilad Green- Is there a way to put the result of the LINQ query into a data table.

Comment: @TushitNagda - Yes :) But I suggest that you just google it :) something along the words "Adding an IEnumerable to a DataTable" or so